# Selecting multiple rows and fetching them simultaneously in treeview in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, pymysql

How can I select multiple rows in a treeview where in the treeview is pulling up data from MySQL database, so that I can display them in my text box. I am able to do this for one row at a time but not sure on how to select multiple entries. I basically have 2 frames in my GUI, left and right frames. Left frame shows a treeview with the animal names and right frame shows a text box. When someone selects the animal name and hit <kbd>Add</kbd> button, it should be added into the right text box. Just want to figure out on how to do this for multiple selections. Below is my code so far.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import pymysql


class Animals_App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Animals")
        self.root.geometry("1350x750+0+0")
        self.root.resizable(FALSE, FALSE)
        title = Label(self.root, text="Animals", font=("times new roman", 30, "bold"), bg="#262626",
                      fg="white").place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1)
        self.root.config(background="powder blue")

        # =====Variables========


        self.animal_var = StringVar()

        # ==For displaying added Animal names on the right text box
        def display_name():
            txt_box.insert(END, 'Animal : ' + self.animal_var.get() + '\n')

        # ==========Frame 1 (Left Frame)===========
        Top_Frame = Frame(self.root, bd=5, relief=RIDGE, bg="white")
        Top_Frame.place(x=10, y=50, width=750, height=620)
        Addbtn = Button(Top_Frame, padx=16, pady=1, bd=7, fg='black', font=('arial', 16, 'bold'), width=4,
        text='Add', bg='powder blue', command=display_name).grid(row=0, column=0)

        Table_Frame = Frame(self.root, bd=5, relief=RIDGE, bg="white")
        Table_Frame.place(x=10, y=130, width=750, height=620)

        scroll_x = Scrollbar(Table_Frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        scroll_y = Scrollbar(Table_Frame, orient=VERTICAL)

        self.Animals_table = ttk.Treeview(Table_Frame,
                                          columns=("animal"),
                                          xscrollcommand=scroll_x.set, yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)
        scroll_x.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        scroll_y.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        scroll_x.config(command=self.Animals_table.xview)
        scroll_y.config(command=self.Animals_table.yview)

        self.Animals_table.heading("animal", text="Animal Names")
        self.Animals_table['show'] = 'headings'

        self.Animals_table.column("animal", width=100)

        self.Animals_table.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.Animals_table.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.get_cursor)
        self.fetch_data()

        # ==========Frame 2 (Right Frame)===========
        Txt_Frame = Frame(self.root, bd=5, relief=RIDGE, bg="white")
        Txt_Frame.place(x=770, y=70, width=580, height=620)

        scroll_y = Scrollbar(Txt_Frame, orient=VERTICAL)
        scroll_y.pack(fill=Y, side=RIGHT)

        txt_box = Text(Txt_Frame, font=("times new roman", 15), bg="lightyellow", fg="black",
                       yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)
        txt_box.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        scroll_y.config(command=txt_box.yview)

        # txt_box.insert(END, 'Animal : ' + '\n')

    def fetch_data(self):
        con = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="animaltree")
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("select * from animals")
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        # rows=["Cow","Deer","Dog","Zebra"]
        if len(rows) != 0:
            self.Animals_table.delete(*self.Animals_table.get_children())
            for row in rows:
                self.Animals_table.insert('', END, values=row)
            con.commit()
        con.close()

    def get_cursor(self, ev):
        cursor_row = self.Animals_table.focus()
        contents = self.Animals_table.item(cursor_row)
        row = contents['values']
        self.animal_var.set(row[0])


root = Tk()
obj = Animals_App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You mean you want to choose multiple items from treeview?

Comment: @CoolCloud Yes that is correct.

Comment: Use `selectmode='multiple'` ? as an option for treeview.

Comment: The default selection mode of `Treeview` is already in multiple.  You need to use `.selection()` instead of `.focus()` to get the selected items.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks for your answer. Another question, what would be best way to store the multiple variables in this case. For single selection this was what I was doing: self.animal_var.set(row[0])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default selection mode of `Treeview` is already in multiple mode.  You need to use `.selection()` instead of `.focus()` to get the selected items.

In order to save the selections, change `self.animal_var` from `StringVar()` to `Variable()` and update `display_name()` and `self.get_cursor()` as below:

```py
class Animals_App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        ...
        self.animal_var = Variable()  # changed from StringVar()

        def display_name():
            txt_box.insert(END, 'Animal : ' + ', '.join(self.animal_var.get()) + '\n')

        ...

    def get_cursor(self, ev):
        self.animal_var.set([ev.widget.item(idx)['values'][0] for idx in ev.widget.selection()])
```